# Ajax update and submission using h:commandButton

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

How to update a div and do partial submission using `<h:commandButton>`, I  have previously used `<p:commandButton>` to do partial submission by setting the ajax attribute to true and the update attribute to :statusBlock, where the id of the `<h:panelGroup>` is statusBlock. I am having some designing issues with `<p:commandButton>` so I cannot use it so I have to use `<h:commandButton>`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is to be done by nesting a [`<f:ajax>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) in it.

In effects,

```
<p:commandButton ... process="@form" update=":statusBlock" />
```

does exactly the same as

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":statusBlock" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Note that the subtle difference with the PrimeFaces equivalent is that PrimeFaces defaults to `@form` in the process/execute, while the `<f:ajax>` one defaults to `@this`, so you might need to explicitly specify `execute="@form"` over all place where you didn't specify the `process` attribute in the PrimeFaces component.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Ajax (asynchronous) POST form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxPOSTForm)

Comment: What does the execute and process attribute do in h:commandButton?

Comment: The `<f:ajax execute>` does exactly the same as `<p:commandButton process>`. The `<f:ajax render>` does exactly the same as `<p:commandButton update>`. The those attributes just specifies which components needs to be executed/processed during the form submit (which defaults in case of PrimeFaces to the whole form and in case of standard JSF to the current component).

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the standard components alongside f:ajax e.g.

```
<h:form id="myForm">       
  <h:commandButton value="Push Me">
     <f:ajax execute="myForm" render="statusBlock" />
  </h:commandButton>
  <h:panelGroup id="statusBlock">
  </h:panelGroup> 
</h:form>
```