# How to forward using h:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I have a view where I have a form with `p:commandButton` and everything works fine beacuse I'm using `forward` and that's what I need:

```
<h:form id="formularioAltas">
    // More code
    <p:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{altasBean.agregarRefaccion()}" update="cboAlmacen cboEstado cboCategoria" />
</h:form>
```

The method `agregarRefaccion()` is **void** so does not changes the page, I think a `forward` takes place after that action because it always has the same url. That is Ok beacuse that is what I need.

In the same view a have another form where I have a problem with `h:commandButton`.

```
<h:form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false">
    // More code
    <h:commandButton id="button" style="background-color: black; color: aliceblue" value="Guardar imagen para #{altasBean.refaccion.idRefaccion}" action="#{altasBean.subirImagen()}" />
</h:form>
```

The `subirImagen()` method is **void** too so I thought a forward would take place after that action... but it doesn't. The page updates and the url changes so that means a redirect did that.

I will always need a forward. No matter if it is a `p:commandButton` or a `h:commandButton`.

I think has something to be with PrimeFaces and  the differences of `p:commandButton` with JSF `h:commandButton`.

**So I need a forward in that** `h:commandButton`.

**Edit**

I always have an url like this **blabla/AlmacenGM/**

but when `h:commandButton` goes the url is: **blabla/AlmacenGM/faces/altas.xhtml**

The url changes. I have tried to return the string `"altas"` int the method `subirImagen()` so a forward should take place  but it still changing the url.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you see when you click on the `p:commandButton` is no "forward", it's just an AJAX-update, and all the components you specify in the `update`-attribute get updated that way. `h:commandButton` does not support AJAX, what is the problem with a `p:commandButton` there?

Comment: @user1983983, `h:commandButton` is not 'ajaxified' like the primefaces' one, however, it does support ajax, as long as you use the `f:ajax` tag into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no forward with `p:commandButton`. It's actually an ajax request what you're peforming, because it's its default behaviour.

However, the standard JSF `h:commandButton` performs a forward request, as long as you return a `String` with the navigation case in your action method. If you see a redirection taking place there, you must be forcing it in your bean side.

**See also:**

- [Ajax update and submission using h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548707/ajax-updation-and-submission-using-hcommandbutton)

Comment: You have to embed a `f:ajax` tag into it. See the related link

Comment: Hey the problem is that I have two forms. When I indicate @form which of them is being selected? I also need to update the form itself. I put something like this: `<f:ajax execute="@form" render=":myForm" />` but sometimes works but some not.

Comment: @KazMiller `@form` is a current form selector. `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />` will process your current form and render it. There are however known issues when two forms come to play in JSF 2.x branches, which are planned to be fixed for 2.3. Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807334/rendering-other-form-by-ajax-causes-its-view-state-to-be-lost-how-do-i-add-this). This shouldn't affect you if you just want to render your current form.