# JSF call a method and display a modal in particular cases

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my .xhtml file I have a button which calls a method from my ManagedBean.
That method should run some tests and if those test are failing I should display a pop-up with an warning or an error.
The warning should not affect the future flow, but the error should stop it.

How can I launch a pop  up from backend?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you do not launch any pop-ups from back-end. Your backing beans have no understanding of the DOM or the browser. What you can do, however, is saving the state in a backing bean and render a given HTML or JavaScript block based on that state. For this you can use the `rendered="#{mybean.myboolean}"` attribute in conjunction with a `update="elementID"` on your button. When clicked, the button will re-render an element with the given ID on the server and inject it into the DOM. If it contains HTML or JS code for a pop-up, then it shows up.

See here for a nice example: [Ajax update and submission using h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548707/ajax-updation-and-submission-using-hcommandbutton)

Or you could try the JSF messages component: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-message-and-messages-example/

**EDIT**: since you seem to be using PrimeFaces, you might also want to look into [Dialogs](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml) and [Validation](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/validation.xhtml).

Comment: your answer seems valid, I'll give it a try, and come back